# TinyMCE real time update

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am using tinymce editor in a form. It works fine. But when I try to use post the form using jquery post method. the tinymce textarea is blank.

```
   $.post("/posts/preview/", $("#PostForm").serialize(), function(data){
      $('#myframe').html(data);
   });
```

All fields are available. Except the tinymce textarea which is blank. I appreciate any help.

Comment: are you getting textarea value from POST?

Comment: @LearneR I am getting all other values except for textarea, the textarea is empty.

Comment: try the `Silvio Silva Andorinha Filho` ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

message is the name you gave the object tinymce

```
tinyMCE.get('mensage').getContent();  /* get vaue tine MCE */

tinymce.get('mensage').setContent('');  /* populate fields and clear fields */
```